# Is there a number besides $\phi$ that either squared or added one gives the same answer?

Tags: quadratics, fibonacci-numbers, constants, golden-ratio

Those who know golden ratio $\phi$ (phi) constant, know for sure that it is an interesting constant. It is roughly $\phi=1.618034...$ . It is present almost everywhere in nature and it has many very interesting properties.

One of the properties of $\phi$ is: $$\phi^2=\phi+1$$ Is there a constant like $\phi$ which squared gives the same answer as itself plus one or is phi special? Is it a real number?

Don't downvote for no reason please.

Comment: How about $\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2}$?

Comment: $1-\phi$ also works.  It is a quadratic equation, and quadratics never have more than 2 solutions.

Comment: This is an elementary quadratic equation...just solve it--there should be two solutions (clearly one of them is negative...as has already been provided).

Comment: The other day you were interested in continued fractions. $\phi$ has the simplest one, and you can see how it leads to $\phi = 1 + \frac{1}{\phi}.$

Comment: Yeah, and it is interesting that reciprocal of phi has the exact same fractional part as phi itself.

Comment: Well, something similar happens in the continued fraction for any $$ x =  \frac{a + \sqrt b}{c} $$ with integers $a,b,c,$ also $b > 0$ but not a square, finally $x > 1$ but $$  -1 < \frac{a - \sqrt b}{c} < 0. $$ The continued fraction is "purely periodic"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is weird, but I'm answering my own question.

Actually just because $\phi$ is a constant kind of misled me, and I forgot that this is normal quadratic equation.

You can solve it like this:

$$-x^2+x+1=0$$
$$\frac{-1\,\pm\,\sqrt{1-4(-1)(1)}}{2(-1)}$$
$$\frac{-1\,\pm\,\sqrt{5}}{-2}$$
$$\frac{1\,\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

Which gives $\phi$ and $1-\phi$.

Comment: Congratulations @KKZiomek, you have just earned a self-learner badge!  :-)

Comment: I didn't even know that's a thing :) thanks.

Comment: Look at the Badges section.  Sf-learner means you answer your own question and draw +3 votes.

Comment: Now I see. I thought it was weird to answer my own question.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider [split-complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-complex_number) or tessarines, then there are four solutions:

$$\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2, \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}2, \frac{1+j\sqrt{5}}2, \frac{1-j\sqrt{5}}2$$

The last two solutions are not real or (usual) complex numbers.